# WSL2- $nvidia-smi command not running

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu 18.04LTS install inside WSL2 and I was able to use GPU. I can run
$nvidia-smi from window run terminal.

However, I can not find any result when I run $nvidia-smi on WSL2

Comment: This should be posted on SuperUser.com, not Stack Overflow (as it's a general computing problem, not programming-related).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the known limitations in documentation from [nvidia](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#known-limitations) :

> NVIDIA Management Library (NVML) APIs are not supported. Consequently,
> nvidia-smi may not be functional in WSL 2.

However you should be able to run https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#unique_1238660826

EDIT: since this answer, nvidia-smi supported since driver [465.42](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#rel-465-42)
I am running it well using 470.57.02.

Comment: Then, how should I check if the driver is installed properly?

Comment: You may run the sample `/usr/local/cuda/samples/4_Finance/BlackScholes` or using docker `docker run --gpus all nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody nbody -gpu -benchmark`

Answer (score 7):

The fix is now available at the nvidia-docs.

```
cp /usr/lib/wsl/lib/nvidia-smi /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
chmod ogu+x /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
```

Source: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#known-limitations

Comment: Not so sure, I get `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.`

Comment: Have you installed CUDA WSL drivers? https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl

Comment: Yes. Cuda is working fine in WSL, but `nvidia-smi` doesn't (above error)

Comment: You can call `nvidia-smi.exe` for the Windows version from WSL

Comment: Just to be clear, you are using WSL and `nvidia-smi` works for you inside WSL? (ie you followed the above procedure and it works?)

Comment: Nah this file does NOT exist !

Comment: Yes. For WSL2( Nvidia Driver Version: 471.68), its working fine for me and the workaround is no longer required. [REFERENCE](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3847#issuecomment-815982671).

Comment: I have the latest driver and I had to use this workaround for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

When I was installing CUDA 11.7.1 in WSL2, a same error raised which noted me

```
Failed to initialize NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system
Failed to properly shut down NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system
```

I fixed it by updating the Windows system to version 19044 21H2.